# Oracle sqlplus query

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I am getting "Invalid Number"

Can anyone please guide me what I am doing wrong here ???

```
select TO_CHAR(a.START_TIME,'YY-MON-DD HH24') as START_TIME, 
        count(*) AS NbOperations,
        SUM(CASE WHEN OPERATION_RESULT=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Success,
        SUM(CASE WHEN OPERATION_RESULT=200 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Cancel,
        SUM(CASE WHEN OPERATION_RESULT=203 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS AppletInternalError,
        SUM(CASE WHEN OPERATION_RESULT=406 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TimeoutWaitForCard,
        SUM(CASE WHEN OPERATION_RESULT=413 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS BillingError,
        SUM(CASE WHEN OPERATION_RESULT=1000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ABANDONNED,
        SUM(CASE WHEN OPERATION_RESULT=1004 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ABANDON_FOR_NEW_OPERATION,
        SUM(CASE WHEN OPERATION_RESULT NOT IN (0,200,203,406,413,1000,1004) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NbOthers
from MyTable1 a, 
      MyTable2 b 
where OPERATION_TYPE in (2,3,4,5) 
and a.OPERATION_TYPE=b.OPERATION_ID 
and a.START_TIME >= to_timestamp('&1', 'YYYY-MM') 
and a.START_TIME < to_timestamp('&2', 'YYYY-MM') + interval '1' month
group by TO_CHAR(a.START_TIME,'YY-MON-DD HH24')
order by TO_CHAR(START_TIME,'YY-MON-DD HH24');
```

Comment: @scaisEdge, this (single quote around 1) is certainly **not** a reason, because syntax requires single quotes when dealing with intervals. Read "Interval literals" in documentation, here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#i38598. What is the reason? No idea; we don't have tables' description nor data, so it is difficult to guess. You tried, but failed :)

Comment: What has this got to do with SQL*Plus specifically, other than the substitution variables? What values are you using for those? They would need to be something like `2018-01` (no quotes).

Comment: By the way, are you sure you want to `order by TO_CHAR(START_TIME,'YY-MON-DD HH24')`? That will give April and August before February and January (assuming English month names).

Answer (score 0):

check the format of your inputs &1 and &2 maybe it doesn't match with your date mask: 'YYYY-MM'. Another possible reason is the contents of the table: OPERATION_TYPE and OPERATION_RESULT are both number datatypes? Possible there are storing things different from a number.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve the issue using below SQL code:

```
select TO_CHAR(a.START_TIME,'YY-MON-DD HH24') as Hourly, count(*) AS NbOperations,
SUM(CASE WHEN OPERATION_RESULT=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Success,
SUM(CASE WHEN OPERATION_RESULT=200 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Cancel,
SUM(CASE WHEN OPERATION_RESULT=203 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS AppletInternalError,
SUM(CASE WHEN OPERATION_RESULT=406 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TimeoutWaitForCard,
SUM(CASE WHEN OPERATION_RESULT=413 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS BillingError,
SUM(CASE WHEN OPERATION_RESULT=1000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ABANDONNED,
SUM(CASE WHEN OPERATION_RESULT=1004 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ABANDON_FOR_NEW_OPERATION,
SUM(CASE WHEN OPERATION_RESULT NOT IN (0,200,203,406,413,1000,1004) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NbOthers
from gsg3_invocation_history a, GSG3_OPERATION_TYPE b where START_TIME >= to_timestamp('&1', 'YYYY-MM')
and START_TIME < to_timestamp('&2', 'YYYY-MM') + interval '1' month and OPERATION_TYPE in (2,3,4,5) and a.OPERATION_TYPE=b.OPERATION_ID
group by TO_CHAR(a.START_TIME,'YY-MON-DD HH24') order by TO_CHAR(START_TIME,'YY-MON-DD HH24');
```